# How to show answer options totals at end of the survey

Tags: limesurvey

We have a survey where we have a question with dual scale array which asks users about certain condition as "mostly" and "presently". And the answer options are  say "Yes","No","May Be".

we wish to show a simple total to the user when he/she submits the survey telling them how many "Yes","No" and "May Be" they have chosen.

i.e You have chosen: Yes - 20, No - 15 , May Be - 10.

How do we do that ?

Comment: This is a specific programming problem that can be solved with code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

You can use Expression Manager for doing that, expanding variables using the ["that" keyword](https://manual.limesurvey.org/Expression_Manager#The_reserved_.27this.27.2C_.27self.27.2C_and_.27that.27_variables). Find an example below.

```
What is the total of row C in q4?  {sum(that.q4.sq_C.NAOK)}
```

I think this will help.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much. We can't inspect the example surveys via lss because of the way LimeSurvey is set up in our organisation ... so have had trouble until finding this snippet of code. This was super-helpful!